Each, neither & either Vs each of, neither of & either of


I like each.
I like either.
I like neither.




I like each of them.
I like either of them.
I like neither of them.


Are these sentences grammatically correct?
I think 1, 2 & 3 are correct but don't give clear meanings.
On the other hand, 4, 5 & 6 giving more clear information.
What do you think?

The first three are not grammatically wrong, but they are very terse and not very idiomatic. For some reason, I find (3) the most acceptable.

Idiomatically I'd probably say "I like both" or "I don't like either". The presence or absence of "of them" is irrelevant.
